# aws localstack fails to deploy global dynamodb table

Tags: aws-cdk, localstack

> cdklocal deploy MyStack

```
Outputs:
DynamoStack.CFOutputmytable = undefined
```

the cdk ts code, was defined like in this example: https://github.com/mavi888/cdk-global-tables/blob/main/lib/level1.ts

using "1st level constructor" the `const globalTable = new CfnGlobalTable(`

I guess because of that "undefined" in the log, when it is done deploy-ing, with no any error provided. I got no dynamo db table created.

What it could be?

--

My localstack defined in the docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:2.0.1
    environment:
      - SERVICES=dynamodb
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - DATA_DIR=/var/lib/localstack/data # Local directory for saving persistent data
      - DEBUG=1
      - PERSISTENCE=0
      - DYNAMODB_SHARE_DB=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It took me some time to figure it out. Until I at last looked carefully to the local-stack log.

```
To find out if AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable is 
   supported in LocalStack Pro, please check out our docs at..
```

Ok. I think I will use local tables..for local then.